# Draw a line on a map but the line not a road

Tags: android, mobile-development

How can I draw a line on a map to detect a live location on that line.
but the line won't be on a road (street), it is a well known line on the map
using google map API.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a line with

```
Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .clickable(true)
        .add(
                new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309)));
```

Check [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial)